# requests fails to download any image from a certain site although all image there is downloadable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Here is the code I use for downloading any image (it always works fine except for this site www.pexels.com) . It actually download the image, but corrupted when it comes to this site ? I wonder why ??

```
url = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/844297/pexels-photo-844297.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"

response = requests.get(url , stream = True)

file= open("Hello.jpg" , 'wb')

for chunk in response.iter_content(10000):
    file.write(chunk)

file.close()
```

Comment: Your code snippet is working perfectly fine for me (creates Hello.jpg with the correct image).

Comment: @stellasia  i edited the link , please try again to download this image  ?

Comment: Maybe try wget instead if you don't mind switching modules

Comment: sorry, even wget has a problem now. It raises a 403 Forbidden error. Maybe that's what's causing the problem with requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `user-agent` to your request headers.

The following code works:

```
import requests

url = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/844297/pexels-photo-844297.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"
}
response = requests.get(url , stream = True, headers=headers)

file= open("Hello.jpg" , 'wb')

for chunk in response.iter_content(10000):
    file.write(chunk)

file.close()
```